# Elasticsearch and Spark, how to write one field to docs

Tags: lucene, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch and Spark. I create an index completely in an rdd and write it using `rdd.saveToEs("index", mappings)`.

Later I want to update the index by overwriting a single field in the doc. But the rdd writing code seems to need the entire doc, writing a map with one property will erase the rest of the doc. For example the docs may have a title, body, and popularity. Populartiy being a Double.

When I recreate the popularity number I now have:

```
RDD[(String, Map[String, Double])]
```

where a single element will have the following value:

```
("doc1", Map(("popularity" -> 1.5d)))
```

if I write this RDD of only popularity fields I believe it will erase the other fields. What I need is some way to do an upsert type of op that overwrites or adds the "popularity" field but leaves the rest of the doc unchanged.

I've read about the `include` and `exclude` mappings but not sure if these apply to this case. When I'm writing the popularity I don't know the rest of the doc structure only the single field.

Comment: Did you find a solution?